# How to show that all numbers in $(0,1)$ satisfy this?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $[0,1]$. Then for any $x\in [0,1]$ . Let $$x=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{r}}{n^{r}}$$ Where $n\geq 2$ , $0\leq a_{r} < n$. That is I want to look at the n-ary(base n) representation of this number.

Then if I denote $A_{n}=\{x\in (0,1)|a_{n}=0\}$. And let $B=\{x\in (0,1)|x\in A_{n} \,\text{for infinitely many}\, n\}$. That is the $\lim\sup A_{n}$ . Then is it true that $B=(0,1)$. ?

How do I proceed to prove this?.

PS:- I am not in a real analysis course. I am trying to construct a counter example akin to Borel Cantelli lemma 2 for probability but I want to apply it to measure space without introducing the notion of "Independence of events".

Comment: The fact that $0.5=0.4999\dots$ makes me think that the $a_r$ are not well defined. Numbers exist that have more than one representation.

Comment: I see...well we can define that $0.5=0.500....$  in decimal representation

Comment: It is obviously false as there are numbers that do not have infinitely many zeroes in their n-ary representation, for example in decimal 1/9=0.11111..., or more generally 1/(n-1)=0.11111... in base n. To prove it formally, use induction on r.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Okay then, Can you help me in proving that $A_{n}\cup A_{m}$ has measure $\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{m}$ . That is , they form an analogue of independent events.

Comment: @drhab . Can you tell me how do I show that $\mu(A_{n}\cup A_{m})=\frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{m}$ . Then they will be akin to the independent events of probability and I can apply BC lemma 2